# Acronyms for same abbreviations with different meaning

Tags: glossaries

I am writing a documentation that includes the two acronyms TCP as in "Tool Control Point" in a robot and TCP as in "Transmission Control Protocol" in computer networking.

I already looked into the two SE questions [One acronym for two words](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113637/one-acronym-for-two-words) and [Same acronym for two words](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208058/same-acronym-for-two-words)

However, I feel like their answers don't really solve my problem. I also suspect this might be an issue of style rather than a LaTeX issue.

In the glossary, I want to create two separate entries, like this:

```
TCP Tool Control Point
TCP Transmission Control Protocol
```

which would be defined in `glossary.tex` somewhat like this:

```
\newacronym{TCP}{TCP}{Tool Control Point}
\newacronym{TCP}{TCP}{Transmission Control Protocol}
```

I would like to refer to these acronyms simply by using the `\acrshort{TCP}` command. Now this obviously doesn't work well, as it is totally context dependent which TCP is meant.

Using the `\acroextra{}` solution as seen in the second link feels wrong as the two abbreviations are used in a completely different context seeing them next to each other in the glossary might be confusing.

My first try was to change one acronym to `TCP*` and use it like this:

```
TCP* Tool Control Point
TCP Transmission Control Protocol
```

and refer to it using `\acrshort{TCP*}`.

Since this is not pretty, I am looking for a good way to accomplish two separate glossary entries with the same acronym. I would also like to stick to `\acrshort{}` to keep the glossary as simple as possible. Thank you for your help!

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{TCP*}{TCP*}{Tool Control Point}
\newacronym{TCP}{TCP}{Transmission Control Protocol}

\begin{document}

\acrshort{TCP} might stand for ``Transmission Control Protocol''.

\acrshort{TCP*} might also stand for ``Tool Control Point'' depending on the
context.

\printglossary[title={Glossary}]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't provide the MWE right from the start. I'm using the `glossaries` package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is to use a hierarchical structure. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[subentrycounter]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{TCP}{name={TCP},description={\nopostdesc}}
\newacronym[parent=TCP]{TCP1}{TCP}{Tool Control Point}
\newacronym[parent=TCP]{TCP2}{TCP}{Transmission Control Protocol}

\begin{document}
First instance: \gls{TCP1} and \gls{TCP2}.

\gls{TCP} might stand for ``Transmission Control Protocol''.

\gls{TCP} might also stand for ``Tool Control Point'' depending on the
context.

\printglossary[title={Glossary},style=treenoname]

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: image of document]

In this case, the `TCP` entry is just a normal entry not an acronym so just reference it with `\gls{TCP}` if required. The `short` field isn't set so `\acrshort{TCP}` won't work. However, I recommend that in the text you actually just reference the appropriate `TCP1` or `TCP2` (change the labels, if desired, to make them easier to remember). If you have hyperlinks this will take the reader to the correct definition.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[subentrycounter]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{TCP}{name={TCP},description={\nopostdesc}}
\newacronym[parent=TCP]{ToolCP}{TCP}{Tool Control Point}
\newacronym[parent=TCP]{TransCP}{TCP}{Transmission Control Protocol}

\begin{document}
First instance: \gls{ToolCP} and \gls{TransCP}.

\gls{TransCP} might stand for ``Transmission Control Protocol''.

\gls{ToolCP} might also stand for ``Tool Control Point'' depending on the
context.

\printglossary[title={Glossary},style=treenoname]

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: image of document]

Comment: This is an awesome solution, thank you very much! I accepted your answer and also upvoted you, but since I have less than 15 reputation it won't show.